# How to filter product from multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have `myObject` array and `myFilter` array. I want to filter product for `["Front Camera": "16 MP and Above"]` all product id shows for `["Front Camera", "16 MP and Above"]` then I do filter `["Ram", "4 GB"]` all product id show  for `["Front Camera", "16 MP and Above"]` that have `["Ram", "4GB"]`

Again applied filter for  `["Front Camera", "8 - 11.9 MP"]` and will product id show  for `["Front Camera", "16 MP and Above"]` and `["Front Camera", "8 - 11.9 MP"]` that have `["Ram", "4GB"]`

Again applied filter for  `["Network Type", "4G"]` , and will product id show  for `["Front Camera": "16 MP and Above"]` and `["Front Camera", "8 - 11.9 MP"]` that have `["Ram": "4GB"]` and  `["Network Type", "4G"]`

You know all the filter normally have ecommerce website. I want to filter like this link  [click](https://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/mi~brand/pr?sid=tyy%2C4io&otracker=nmenu_sub_Electronics_0_Mi&p[]=facets.serviceability[]%3Dfalse)  only for checkbox

```
var myObject = [
{
    "ProId": 12,
    "ProName": "Samsung Galaxy A9",
    "AttriValue": {
        "ProductId": "12",
        "Front Camera": "16 MP and Above",
        "Internal Memory": "128 GB and Above",
        "Network Type": "4G",
        "Primary Camera": "16 MP and Above",
        "Ram": "6 GB"
    }
},  
{
    "ProId": 11,
    "ProName": "Vivo Y95",
    "AttriValue": {
        "ProductId": "11",
        "Front Camera": "16 MP and Above",
        "Internal Memory": "64 GB",
        "Network Type": "4G",
        "Primary Camera": "13 - 15.9 MP",
        "Ram": "4 GB"
    }
},  
{
    "ProId": 10,
    "ProName": "OPPO A7",
    "AttriValue": {
        "ProductId": "10",
        "Front Camera": "16 MP and Above",
        "Internal Memory": "64 GB",
        "Network Type": "4G",
        "Primary Camera": "13 - 15.9 MP",
        "Ram": "4 GB"
    }
}
{
    "ProId": 16,
    "ProName": "Samsung Feature Phone",
    "AttriValue": {
        "Sim Type": "Single",        
    }
}
]
```

and my filter array is

```
var myFilter = [
  ["Front Camera", "16 MP and Above"],
  ["Front Camera", "8 - 11.9 MP"], ​
  ["Internal Memory", "128 GB and Above"], ​
  ["Primary Camera", "16 MP and Above"],
  ["Primary Camera", "8 - 12.9 MP"],
  ["Network Type", "4G"],
  ["Primary Camera", "16 MP and Above"], ​
  ["Ram", "4 GB"],
  ["Sim Type", "Single"]
]
```

Comment: what should happen with the same key? is it then an OR condition? what have you tried?

Comment: ["Primary Camera", "16 MP and Above"] and 
  ["Primary Camera", "8 - 12.9 MP"] with the same key then filter should work for also with same key when applied more filter

Comment: You mean, we can select both these filter together `["Primary Camera", "16 MP and Above"] and ["Primary Camera", "8 - 12.9 MP"]` along with the `RAM` filter

Comment: yes when applied filter for ["Network Type", "4G"] , and will product id show for ["Front Camera": "16 MP and Above"] and ["Front Camera", "8 - 11.9 MP"] that have ["Ram": "4GB"] and ["Network Type", "4G"] please see the link that i have mentioned above

Comment: please add the use cases along with the results.

Comment: 11,10 product id when applied filter for ["Network Type", "4G"] , and will product id show for ["Front Camera": "16 MP and Above"] and ["Front Camera", "8 - 11.9 MP"] that have ["Ram": "4GB"] and ["Network Type", "4G"]  please see the link that i have mentioned abov

Comment: anyone reply my question..please help

Answer (score 0):

You can check the solution below.

```js
var myObject = [{
    "ProId": 12,
    "ProName": "Samsung Galaxy A9",
    "AttriValue": {
      "ProductId": "12",
      "Front Camera": "16 MP and Above",
      "Internal Memory": "128 GB and Above",
      "Network Type": "4G",
      "Primary Camera": "16 MP and Above",
      "Ram": "6 GB"
    }
  },
  {
    "ProId": 11,
    "ProName": "Vivo Y95",
    "AttriValue": {
      "ProductId": "11",
      "Front Camera": "8 - 11.9 MP",
      "Internal Memory": "64 GB",
      "Network Type": "4G",
      "Primary Camera": "13 - 15.9 MP",
      "Ram": "4 GB"
    }
  },
  {
    "ProId": 10,
    "ProName": "OPPO A7",
    "AttriValue": {
      "ProductId": "10",
      "Front Camera": "16 MP and Above",
      "Internal Memory": "64 GB",
      "Network Type": "4G",
      "Primary Camera": "13 - 15.9 MP",
      "Ram": "4 GB"
    }
  }
];

var myFilter = [
  ["Front Camera", "16 MP and Above"],
  ["Front Camera", "8 - 11.9 MP"],
  ["Internal Memory", "128 GB and Above"],
  ["Primary Camera", "16 MP and Above"],
  ["Primary Camera", "8 - 12.9 MP"],
  ["Network Type", "4G"],
  ["Primary Camera", "48 MP and Above"],
  ["Ram", "6 GB"]
];
let newFilter = {};
myFilter.forEach(function(obj){
  if(newFilter[obj[0]] == undefined){
    newFilter[obj[0]] = [obj[1]];
  }else{
    let oldValue = newFilter[obj[0]];
    newFilter[obj[0]] = oldValue.concat([obj[1]])
  }
});

var result = myObject.filter((obj) => {
  let response = true;
  Object.keys(newFilter).forEach(function(key){
    response = response && newFilter[key].indexOf(obj.AttriValue[key]) >= 0
  });
  return response;
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: What is lowest version of JS you need ?

Comment: i dont want to change myFilter can you change myfilter in your format

Answer (score 0):

Your filter did not return anything (by machine processing) - in case you have checkboxes, JS do not know 6GB is better than 4GB, so in case I add also 6 GB to filter, get A9 as result (in case you are happy with, please accept answer - below voting buttons):

```js
function run() {
    var simpleFilter = processFilters(myFilter);
    var result = getProducts(simpleFilter, myObject);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
}
function getProducts(filter, products) {
    var retVal = []; // products matching filter criteria
    for(var item in products) {
        var itemCheck = products[item]; // get item data by its #
        var selected = true; // hope we will keep it here
        var itemsChecked = 0; // # of filter items processed
        for(var at in itemCheck.AttriValue) { // iterate attributes
            if(filter[at]) { // at = name of attribute, is at group in filter ?
                itemsChecked++;
                if(filter[at][itemCheck.AttriValue[at]] === undefined) {
                    /* // group at found, but value itemCheck.AttriValue[at] not
                    console.log("Removing " + JSON.stringify(itemCheck));
                    console.log(at + " does not include " + itemCheck.AttriValue[at]);
                    //*/
                    selected = false; // skip product by flag change
                }
            }
        }
        if(selected && itemsChecked == filter.size) retVal.push(itemCheck); // IF we passed ALL unique filter groups without clearing selection, so keep that product
    }
    return retVal;
}
function processFilters(filter) { // double associated search array
    var retVal = [], uniqueItems = 0;
    for(var i=0;i<filter.length;i++) { // 1st level of filter array
        if(retVal[filter[i][0]]) retVal[filter[i][0]][filter[i][1]] = true;
        else { // append next item or below create empty associative array and set its 1st key to true
            var at = {}
            at[filter[i][1]] = true;
            retVal[filter[i][0]] = at;
            uniqueItems++;
        }
    }
    retVal.size = uniqueItems; // save filter groups #
    console.log("Filter size: ", uniqueItems);
    return retVal; // return processed filter
}
var myObject = [
    {
        "ProId": 12,
        "ProName": "Samsung Galaxy A9",
        "AttriValue": {
            "ProductId": "12",
            "Front Camera": "16 MP and Above",
            "Internal Memory": "128 GB and Above",
            "Network Type": "4G",
            "Primary Camera": "16 MP and Above",
            "Ram": "6 GB"
        }
    },
    {
        "ProId": 11,
        "ProName": "Vivo Y95",
        "AttriValue": {
            "ProductId": "11",
            "Front Camera": "16 MP and Above",
            "Internal Memory": "64 GB",
            "Network Type": "4G",
            "Primary Camera": "13 - 15.9 MP",
            "Ram": "4 GB"
        }
    },
    {
        "ProId": 10,
        "ProName": "OPPO A7",
        "AttriValue": {
            "ProductId": "10",
            "Front Camera": "16 MP and Above",
            "Internal Memory": "64 GB",
            "Network Type": "4G",
            "Primary Camera": "13 - 15.9 MP",
            "Ram": "4 GB"
        }
    },
    {
        "ProId": 16,
        "ProName": "Samsung Feature Phone",
        "AttriValue": {
            "Sim Type": "Single",
        }
    }
]
var myFilter = [
    ["Front Camera", "16 MP and Above"],
    ["Front Camera", "8 - 11.9 MP"],
    ["Internal Memory", "128 GB and Above"],
    ["Primary Camera", "16 MP and Above"],
    ["Primary Camera", "8 - 12.9 MP"],
    ["Network Type", "4G"],
    ["Primary Camera", "16 MP and Above"],
    ["Ram", "4 GB"],
    ["Ram", "6 GB"],
    ["Sim Type", "Single"]
]
run();
```

In case your filter looks like this, no need to transform it by processFilters and you can directly pick if particular item match:

```
var myFilter = {
    "Front Camera": {
        "16 MP and Above":true,
        "8 - 11.9 MP":true
    },
    "Internal Memory": {
        "128 GB and Above":true
    },
    "Primary Camera": {
        "16 MP and Above":true,
        "8 - 12.9 MP":true
    },
    "Network Type": {
        "4G": true
    },
    "Primary Camera": {
        "16 MP and Above":true
    },
    "Ram": {
        "4 GB": true,
        "6 GB": true
    }
};
```

Comment: Quite simple and quick code (except processFilters) => 100% compatible.

Comment: You can simply add/delete filter by example:
myFilter["Internal Memory"]["64 GB"] = true;
delete myFilter.Ram["4 GB"];

Comment: You cannot create multiple levels of properties, but also these property definitions are possible:
var x="1 TB";
myFilter["Memory"] = {"64 GB":true};
myFilter["Memory"][x] = true;

Comment: I suppose false is not valid input - true is only because you cannot have associative array key without value, but if you uncheck some filter checkbox, you should delete its key:value pair... Or do you want a "fuzzy" selection - suppose you want all or product matching all filter values.

Comment: Probably better variant (filter[at][itemCheck.AttriValue[at]] === undefined) products with false will be kept or if (filter[at][itemCheck.AttriValue[at]] != true) they will be filter out...

Comment: Line 14. if(filter[at][itemCheck.AttriValue[at]] == undefined) { now and you can uncomment logs (by adding one slash only /* -> //*)  below to see why products were filtered out.

Comment: Hope better now, in case you move itemsChecked++; next to following IF, it will not found A9 as it does not have new Sim Type defined. Problem was I am working opposite way (looking for product in filter and not filter in product), so now there is # of filter unique items and # of attribute items processed and product is selected only when they are same (and match indeed).

Answer (score 0):

Because of the unclear result, you could use a scoring system and count how many key/value pairs match and take this count for sorting the array descending.

This approach takes a `Map` for collecting same keys and `Set` for each value. This map is converted to an array for later easily iterating key and `Set`.

The cound checks if `AttriValue` exists and if the value is in the `Set`.

```js
var data = [{ ProId: 12, ProName: "Samsung Galaxy A9", AttriValue: { ProductId: "12", "Front Camera": "16 MP and Above", "Internal Memory": "128 GB and Above", "Network Type": "4G", "Primary Camera": "16 MP and Above", Ram: "6 GB" } }, { ProId: 11, ProName: "Vivo Y95", AttriValue: { ProductId: "11", "Front Camera": "16 MP and Above", "Internal Memory": "64 GB", "Network Type": "4G", "Primary Camera": "13 - 15.9 MP", Ram: "4 GB" } }, { ProId: 10, ProName: "OPPO A7", AttriValue: { ProductId: "10", "Front Camera": "16 MP and Above", "Internal Memory": "64 GB", "Network Type": "4G", "Primary Camera": "13 - 15.9 MP", Ram: "4 GB" } }, { ProId: 16, ProName: "Samsung Feature Phone", AttriValue: { "Sim Type": "Single" } }],
    filter = [["Front Camera", "16 MP and Above"], ["Front Camera", "8 - 11.9 MP"], ["Internal Memory", "128 GB and Above"], ["Primary Camera", "16 MP and Above"], ["Primary Camera", "8 - 12.9 MP"], ["Network Type", "4G"], ["Primary Camera", "16 MP and Above"], ["Ram", "4 GB"], ["Sim Type", "Single"]],
    map = Array.from(filter.reduce((m, [k, v]) => m.set(k, (m.get(k) || new Set).add(v)), new Map)),
    result = data
        .map(o => [
            map.reduce((c, [k, s]) => c + (k in o.AttriValue && s.has(o.AttriValue[k])), 0),
            o
        ])
        .sort(([a], [b]) => b - a);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

The use of the filter values as an array of sets works with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and returns only this items who have **all** properties with wanted values - in this case you get an empty array.

```js
var data = [{ ProId: 12, ProName: "Samsung Galaxy A9", AttriValue: { ProductId: "12", "Front Camera": "16 MP and Above", "Internal Memory": "128 GB and Above", "Network Type": "4G", "Primary Camera": "16 MP and Above", Ram: "6 GB" } }, { ProId: 11, ProName: "Vivo Y95", AttriValue: { ProductId: "11", "Front Camera": "16 MP and Above", "Internal Memory": "64 GB", "Network Type": "4G", "Primary Camera": "13 - 15.9 MP", Ram: "4 GB" } }, { ProId: 10, ProName: "OPPO A7", AttriValue: { ProductId: "10", "Front Camera": "16 MP and Above", "Internal Memory": "64 GB", "Network Type": "4G", "Primary Camera": "13 - 15.9 MP", Ram: "4 GB" } }, { ProId: 16, ProName: "Samsung Feature Phone", AttriValue: { "Sim Type": "Single" } }],
    filter = [["Front Camera", "16 MP and Above"], ["Front Camera", "8 - 11.9 MP"], ["Internal Memory", "128 GB and Above"], ["Primary Camera", "16 MP and Above"], ["Primary Camera", "8 - 12.9 MP"], ["Network Type", "4G"], ["Primary Camera", "16 MP and Above"], ["Ram", "4 GB"], ["Sim Type", "Single"]],
    map = Array.from(filter.reduce((m, [k, v]) => m.set(k, (m.get(k) || new Set).add(v)), new Map)),
    result = data.filter(o => map.every(([k, s]) => k in o.AttriValue && s.has(o.AttriValue[k])));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```